# How to invoke client ActiveX via javascript

Tags: javascript, com, activex

I want to let server to invoke client ActiveX via javascript. The script work well as it run on my local system. Then I place it into Apache Server and it's malfunction.

Script:

```
<object id="lv_obj"  classid = "CLSID:30A92485-94D2-4CBA-AC32-EF276B7F777B" CODEBASE="" ></OBJECT>

try {
   document.all.lv_obj.Init("PCS_Tes");
} catch (err) {
   window.alert("错误信息: " + err.message);
}
```

I guess the reason is script on server can't invoke user client ActiveX. If I need config something on Apache?

Comment: This question does not make sense.  What are you trying to do, and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an IE security setting.